# Load model from Maya 8.5 to THREE.JS

Tags: maya, three.js

I have created a really simple model in Maya 8.5 to test in THREE.JS, the model is exported as .obj and converted to a JSON file using a Python script from the THREE.JS github repo.

The conversion looks like it worked fine as it is certainly a valid JSON object with all the data in there. The problem is when I load it in I get the following warning:

DEPRECATED: [js/jumper.js] seems to be using old model format

Does this mean the .obj format changed somehow or am I missing something else? Here is the code I'm using to load the object. I have other native shapes showing up fine so I know the setup is correct, its just this model loading that I'm having trouble with.

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load("js/jumper.js", function( geometry ) {
        jumper = new Three.Mesh(geometry, new Three.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x88000}));
        jumper.scale.set(10,10,10);
        scene.add(jumper);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Seems that even if I load in one of the models from the git repo I still have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after posting on three.js github forum, I have found that you will get that error even if there are problems in your code which is run in the handler which is run when the model loads. Therefore all code should be checked in the handler even if the error points to an issue with the model.

Answer (score 1):

I have just started to made a simple exporter to convert from OBJ to Three.JS version 3.1 JSON format. So if you just export an OBJ fro MAYA and use the program here, you might be able to export.

https://github.com/theMaxscriptGuy/Windows_Programs/tree/master/Obj_To_ThreeJS

Thanks